# Declaring and using PHP namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

Please help to identify what is wrong in this code.

I have this folder structure:

> ```
> Project
> |--index.php
> |-src
>    |--db
>       |--Role.php
> ```

Role.php

```
<?php
namespace src\db;

class Role extends Table
{
    public $name    = "";
    
    // TODO - Insert your code here
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // TODO - Insert your code here
    }
}
```

index.php

```
   <?php
    
    use src\db\Role;
    
    $role = new Role();
    
    $role->name = "Admin";
    
    $role->Save();
```

But php cannot find the class. It throws this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'src\db\Role' not found in C:\wamp64\www\Project\index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using an autoloader, then you have to include the file in which the class is defined, using either require (https://www.php.net/manual/function.require.php) or  include (https://www.php.net/manual/function.include.php)

Comment: I added the auto loader in the index page and it is working. Thanks.